# Save rendered image before compositing without re-rendering

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I have rendered an image. It took a long time to render it.

I also have compositing nodes. For clarity let's call the image after rendering "image A", and the final image after compositing "image B". I would like to tweak the compositing nodes without re-rendering. Now I can do it, because Blender is still running, but if I close and start Blender, image A will disappear, and I have to render again.

So I would like to save Image A now (in openexr multilayer format, with all the render passes), so that the next time I can put it into an Image input node, and tweak the compositing nodes without re-rendering.

I can save image B from the UV/Image Editor with F3, but I found no way to save image A - although it is still in Blender now. How can I do it?

Comment: That should be easy.. Either mute the node tree / plug the output from the render layer into the Composite node or choose Render Layer in the layers section in the UV / Image Editor..

Comment: @MrZak Thank you, actually the answer is even simpler - see my answer. Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it in the meantime. The EXR file of image B actually also contains image A, I just have to switch the "Layer" in the Image input node. I hope in the future this question and answer will still help somebody.

Comment: Also note that this will be possible only if that image is actual EXR (and Multilayer also).